# Android indeterminate progressbar has strange lines

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I implemented a interdeterminate progressbar like they exmplain here:
http://www.zoftino.com/android-progressbar-and-custom-progressbar-examples

I styled it with this code:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyProgressBarSpinner" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progressspinner</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">200dp</item>
</style>
```

**progressspinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:top="16dp"
    android:bottom="16dp">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="0"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:toDegrees="360">
                <shape  android:shape="ring"
                        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
                        android:thickness="3.8sp"
                        android:useLevel="true">
                <solid
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#79bac6" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="90"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:toDegrees="180">
                <shape  android:shape="ring"
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
                    android:thickness="3.8sp"
                    android:useLevel="true">
                    <solid
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#7985c6" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="360"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:toDegrees="0">
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/picture">
                </bitmap>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Now the problem is, that I get this strange lines from the two rings in my progressbar and I couldn't figure out how to prevent this. You can see it on this image:

[image]

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Can you please provide android:src="@drawable/picture" file. Picture drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below two lines of code from spinner xml.

> android:top="16dp"
>
> android:bottom="16dp"

This is adding extra lines inside progress bar where you are facing the problem.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:toDegrees="360">
                    <shape
                        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
                        android:shape="ring"
                        android:thickness="3.8sp"
                        android:useLevel="true">
                        <solid
                            android:width="1dp"
                            android:color="#79bac6"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="90"
                    android:toDegrees="180">
                    <shape
                        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
                        android:shape="ring"
                        android:thickness="3.8sp"
                        android:useLevel="true">
                        <solid
                            android:width="1dp"
                            android:color="#7985c6"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item
                android:width="60dp"
                android:height="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="360"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="0">
                    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">
                    </bitmap>
                </rotate>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**How to get my image smaller?**

For this, you have to use item width and height params with gravity.

**Example:**

```
<item
     android:width="60dp"
     android:height="60dp"
     android:gravity="center">
```

Comment: Wow, this really works. Do you know how to get my image smaller? Because when I delete these lines it is bigger then the two circles and I tried everything to get it smaller but didn't succeed.

Comment: @progNewbie: I hope above answer will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have any other idea?